# Django dynamic homepage

Tags: python, django

I have a lots of apps, but I want to generate all app's data on my homepage. Here's my apps:blog,members

I want to show blogs and my members on my homepage
I know that if I want to generate one app's data,I can do this:
blog/urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', ListView.as_view(
    queryset=Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10],
    template_name='blog1.html')),
```

and in blog1.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block blog %}
{% for post in blog_post %}
<div id="blog-wrapper" class="bgrid-third s-bgrid-half mob-bgrid-whole     group">
<article class="bgrid">
            <h5>{{ post.date }} </h5>
               <h3><a href="/{{ post.id }}"><div class = "entry-title">{{ post.title }}</div></a></h3>
                <p>{{ post.user }}</p>
               <p><div class = "post_body">{{ post.body|safe|linebreaks }}</div></p>
            </article>
</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block member %}
```

Here when I go to the url,I can see all blogs I write,but now I want to see blogs and members(another app) on one page, so how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to use [`ListView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview)'s [`get_context_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/class-based-views/mixins-multiple-object/#django.views.generic.list.MultipleObjectMixin.get_context_data) method.

Create view in your project's `views.py`:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

# Import your models here.


class HomepageView(ListView):
    model = Post
    ordering = '-date'
    template_name = 'blog1.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(HomepageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['members'] = Member.objects.all()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(HomepageView, self).get_queryset()[:10]
```

Then, change `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import url

# Import ``HomepageView`` here.


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', HomepageView.as_view(), name='homepage'),
    # Other patterns here.
]
```

Now you can access posts using `posts` variable and members using `members` variable.

Comment: def get_data():
    return {
        "post": Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10],
        "user": UserProfile.objects.all()[:10]
    }

Answer (score 0):

```
from .models import Post
from member.models import UserProfile


def get_data():
return {
    "post": Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")[:10],
    "user": UserProfile.objects.all()[:10]
}
```

then in my blog1.html:

```
{% extends "index.html" %}
{% block blog %}
{% for post in object_list.post %}
<div id="blog-wrapper" class="bgrid-third s-bgrid-half mob-bgrid-whole group">
            <article class="bgrid">
            <h5>{{ post.date }} </h5>
               <h3><a href="/{{ post.id }}"><div class = "entry-title">{{ post.title }}</div></a></h3>
                <p>{{ post.user }}</p>
               <p><div class = "post_body">{{ post.body|safe|linebreaks }}</div></p>
            </article>
</div>
            {% endfor %}


{% endblock %}

{% block member %}
{% for post in object_list.user  %}
                <div class="bgrid member">

                   <div class="member-header">

                        <div class="member-pic">
                                <img src="{{ post.portrait }}" alt=""/>
                        </div>

                      <div class="member-name">
                         <h3>{{ post.user }}</h3>
                         <span>Creative Director</span>
                      </div>

                   </div>

                   <p>{{ post.intro }}</p>

                   <ul class="member-social">
                      <li><a href="{{ post.github }}"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                       <li><a href="{{ post.google_plus }}"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a></li>
                   </ul>

                </div> <!-- /member -->
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```